# PIG regex extract then filter the unnamed regex tuple

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have a string as:

```
[["structure\/","structure\/home_page\/","structure\/home_page\/headline_list\/","structure\/home_page\/latest\/","topic\/","topic\/location\/","topic\/location\/united_states\/","topic\/location\/united_states\/ohio\/","topic\/location\/united_states\/ohio\/franklin\/","topic\/news\/","topic\/news\/politics\/","topic\/news\/politics\/elections\/,topic\/news\/politics\/elections\/primary\/"]]
```

I want to regex_extract_all to turn it into elements in a tuple and sepereated by `","`. Then I need to filter out the ones don't contain `structure` and `location`.
However, I got an error that can't filter regex type. Any idea?
By the way, the ending goal is to parse out the longest hierarchy like `(topic|news|politics|elections|primary)`

update the script:

```
data = load load '/web/visit_log/20160303' 
            USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as json:map[];
a = foreach data generate json#section as sec_type;
b = foreach act_flt GENERATE ..host, REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(act_type, 'topic..(?!location)(.*?)"') as extr;
store b into /user/tad/sec_hir
```

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: added updated script

Comment: Actually, I want to extract the longest string that doesn't contain structure and location.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for filter matches seems incorrect.The data doesn't seem to have () in it.

```
c = filter b by not extr matches '(structure|location)';
```

Try changing this to

```
 c = filter b by not (extr matches 'structure|location');
```

Comment: I am thinking of the regex part is not correct. I updated the script.